# Reducing one frequency in song

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing, fft

How would I take a song input and output the same song without certain frequencies?

Based on my research so far, the song should be broken down into chucks, FFT it, reduce the target frequencies, iFFT it, and stitch the chunks back together. However, I am unsure if this is the right approach to take, and if so, how I would convert from the audio to FFT input (what seems to be a vector matrix), how to reduce the target frequencies, and how to convert back from the FFT output to audio, and how to restitch.

For background, my grandpa loves music. However, recently he cannot listen to it, as he has become hypersensitive to certain frequencies within songs. I'm a high school student who has some background coding, and am just getting into algorithmic work and thus have very little experience using these algorithms. Please excuse me if these are basic questions; any pointers would be helpful.

EDIT: So far, I've understood the basic premise of fft (through basic 3blue1brown yt videos and the like) and that it is available through scipy/numpi, and figured out how to convert from youtube to 0.25 second chunks in a wav format.

Comment: Please, add the references you consulted and the code you tried if any.

Comment: Using a Fourier-Transformation (FT), reducing the desired frequencies and transforming it back seams for me the right way.

Comment: If you use FFT, in order to avoid issues at the borders to a FFT blocks, you might use a kind of "overlap-save" method. It you only want to reduce the lower or higher frequencies, a simple FIR filter (like a Kaiser filter) could do it. You should provide more information on these frequencies you would like to cancel. Note also that there is a *signal processing* SE site where such kind of questions have already been asked

Comment: @Happy-Monad updated with what I've done so far

Comment: This is a great article that may interest you https://willdrevo.com/fingerprinting-and-audio-recognition-with-python/ and also this free book http://greenteapress.com/thinkdsp/thinkdsp.pdf

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60295951/781723, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/64004/5874.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is right.

Concerning subquestions:
`from the audio to FFT input` - assign audio samples to real part of complex signal, imaginary part is zero

`how to reduce the target frequencies` - multiply FFT results near needed frequency by smooth (to diminish artifacts) function that becomes zero at that freqency and reaches 1.0 some samples apart

`how to convert back` - just make inverse FFT (don't forget about scale multiplier like 1/N) and copy real part into audio channel

---

Also consider using of simpler digital filtering - band-stop or **notch** filter.

Arbitrary found [example1](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11290/linear-phase-notch-filter-band-reject-filter-implementation-in-c) [example2](https://www.dsprelated.com/showcode/173.php)
(calculation of parameters perhaps requires some understanding of DSP)

Comment: I see. For number 1, how would I actually take the audio and assign it to the real part of the complex signal? I tried googling it and nothing seems to come up.

Comment: I dealt with wav-files only. You perhaps want to work with audio stream  - so interception is another question, it depends on operation system and another details.

Comment: I am working with wav files, but I still cannot understand how to assign it to the real part of complex signal.

Comment: Find data chunk of the left or right channel - it is like array of Int16 data and assign element by element to floats needed for fft.